# How to estimate position from noisy angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, numerical-methods

First of all: I think this problem has been studied very well (I assume in the field of surveying or navigation), but I was unable to find any information as I do not know what it is called.

EDIT: As @Rahul mentioned this is called *resection problem*. Wikipedia points to various methods but they usually require *exact* measurements and assume that you have $n=3$.

---

Suppose we know the exact position of a number $n \geq 3$ points (in the example below $n=4$) $P_i$ in the plane. (We can assume that those points are in some non degenerate configuration.) Furthermore we are at some unknown location $P_0$ looking in an unknown direction $\hat x_1$. Now we can observe the angles $\alpha_i$ of how much the direction we see each point deviates from our direction $\hat x_1$.

With these observations $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ we'd like to determine $P_0$ (as well as the direction $\hat x_1$, but that is trivial once we know $P_0$). The problem is that the angles $\alpha_i$ are affected by noise i.e. cannot be measured exactly. (We can assume that they have an e.g. normally distributed error, or whatever is convenient. )

Is there a way to "robustly" estimate $P_0$?

Is there a well known name for this problem?

[image]

Comment: What about maximum likelihood estimation?

Comment: This appears to be known as [resection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_resection).

Comment: Sounds like a Kalman filter could be useful here.

Comment: You might try searching on "resection error analysis".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Least Squares via Inscribed Angle theorem

This is an algorithm I came up with but I'm not sure whether it is actually used or how well it works. I will provide an implementation for comparision in the future.

*First consider the case where we have exact measurements:*

Given the angles $\beta_{ij} = \alpha_{i}-\alpha_{j}$ we can construct a circle $c_{ij}$ of all points under which  the line segment defined by $P_i$ and $P_j$ is visible under the angle $\beta_{ij}$ with the inscribed angle theorem.

For example in the special case where $\beta = \pi/2$, then this circle has center $\frac{1}{2}(P_i + P_j)$ and radius $\Vert P_i - P_j \Vert /2$. (This can be explained using the Thales Theorem as a special case of the inscribed angle theorem.)

If we take a set of such circles we know that $P_0$ must be in their intersection.

Here is a diagram of two of these circles for the arbitrary case of $\beta_{12} = 45^\circ$ and $\beta_{23} = -140^\circ$.

[image]

The center and radius of circle $c_{ij}$ is fully defined by a function of $P_i$, $P_j$, and $\beta_{ij}$ (via the inscribed angle theorem). (see appendix) Similarly, $c_{jk}$ is fully defined by $P_j$, $P_k$, and $\beta_{jk}$. The intersection of $c_{ij}$ and $c_{jk}$ is thus $\{P_j, P_0\}$, so the ambiguity is resolved (just select the point that isn't $P_j$). This fails however in the degenerate case of all $P$ being on the same circle (in which case they will all yield the same redundant equation - imagine if $P_k$ in the above diagram was on the orange $c_{ij}$). In general, the intersection of two circles is determined by [solving the linear system formed by subtracting their equations](https://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection.html).

This whole process is also [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027120/given-visible-landmarks-of-known-location-and-no-magnetic-compass-can-you-calc).

*Let us now consider the noisy case:*

In this case the $n$ circles, and the $n$ linear equations we get will not necessarily intersect in a single point, so we cannot directly solve the system of linear equations. But instead we can consider it as a least squares problem, to find a point that is close to the pairwise intersections.

Of course, this isn't optimal in any probabilistic sense with regard to the relative noises of the various bearing measurements. For example, in a practical setting, a very far away landmark might be harder to accurately determine bearing to since it is harder to see. If this is to be accounted for, note that the measurement noise will enter the equations nonlinearly (the transformation from bearings to circles via the inscribed angle theorem is nonlinear) and will require an approximation like the answer given by @jnez71.

---

### Appendix: Construction of the circles

#### Case A: $\beta_{ij} \leq \pi/2$

[image]
Let us assume ssuming $P_0$, $P_i$, $P_j$ are in positive orientation.

Here the inscribed angle theorem tells us $\gamma = 2\beta_{ij}$ (in the picture $i=1, j=2$). So we can compute $M_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(P_i + P_j)$ and therefore $\angle (M_{ij}, C, P_i) = \gamma /2$. Let $R$ be a rotation matrix of $90^\circ$ $$R = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$. Then we can write

$$C = M_{ij} + t R \frac{(P_j - P_i)}{\Vert P_j - P_i \Vert}$$

where $t$ is the signed distance from $M_{ij}$ to $C$,

and then when considering the trangle $C,M_{ij},P_j$ we see that

$$\frac{t}{\Vert P_j - M_{ij} \Vert} = \tan(\pi/2 - \gamma/2)$$

which we can solve for $t$ which then yields $C$. Then the radius $r = \Vert C - P_i \Vert$ and we can easily write down the equation of the circle.

#### Case B: $\beta_{ij} \geq \pi/2$

[image]

Since we used $t$ as a *signed* distance (hence the assumption about the positive orientation), we can also apply the same formula from the first case.

Comment: The system of equations for the intersections is *not linear*... But, if you linearize it, and then solve least-squares, it is equivalent to using an extended Kalman filter's correct-step with scalar covariance. Since we don't know where a good place to linearize is, we can iteratively linearize, solve, and re-linearize about the new solution. This is exactly what I did in my answer above. I am 99% sure that the deeper you dig into this problem, the more you will find that my answer is the canonical approach these days. Sorry for randomly popping up; I looked at this again to show a friend.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you think is non linear? Perhaps I wasn't completely clear:  Consider the equations: $c_{1,2}: \:\: (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = r_1^2$, $c_{2,3}: \:\: (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 = r_1^2$. Subtracting $c_{2,3}$ from $c_{1,2}$ cancels out the quadratic terms in $x$ and $y$, and we're left with a linear equation in $x$ and $y$. (The resulting equation is $2x (x_2-x_1) + 2y(y_2-y_1) + x_1^2 - x_2^2 +y_1^2 - y_2^2 = r_1^2 - r_2^2$.) And we can do this for all pairs of distinct points and get a linear system. I try to find the code again where I used this, to show some examples.

Comment: You don't know $r_1$ or $r_2$. You said you only know the landmark positions ($P_i$) relative to some world-fixed coordinate-system. You explicitly do not know your own position ($P_0$) else there wouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: We have measurements of bearings ($\alpha_i$), not ranges ($r_i$). The relationship between a bearing measurement and your position and heading is $\alpha_i = \tan^{-1}\big{(}\dfrac{y_i - y_0}{x_i - x_0}\big{)} - \alpha_0 + \epsilon_i$, which is the nonlinear stochastic ($\epsilon_i$ is noise) equation I showed you an approach for. Everything in that equation is known except your state $x_0$, $y_0$, $\alpha_0$, and the noise $\epsilon_i$. The only knowns are the landmark positions $x_i$, $y_i$, and the measurements $\alpha_i$ like you originally wanted.

Comment: It isn't clear how you are using the bearing measurements in your method? It seems like you are [trying to do this](https://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection.html) even though you don't know the radius of the circles.

Comment: @jnez71 Yes we do not have ranges, but the radii $r_i$ can be determined from the (signed) angle $\beta_{ij}$ under which we see the line segment $P_i$, $P_j$. Knowing the coordinates of $P_i$ and $P_j$ we can determine a circle on which $P_0$ must be with the inscribed angle theorem.

Comment: I'll have to add a drawing, that maybe explains it a little bit better than words:)

Comment: I think I get what you're doing now, though your previous comment was misleading. If you write $(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = r_1^2$ it seems like you are describing a circle centered at $P_0$ that touches $P_1$, where $r_1$ is the range from $P_0$ to $P_1$. That isn't what you meant. You meant that "circle 1" is generated by $P_i$, $P_j$, and $\beta_{ij} = \alpha_i - \alpha_j$ and has known center point $[x_1, y_1] \neq P_1$ and radius $r_1$, and we only know $P_0$ is somewhere on this circle. I'll suggest an edit to your problem with an image of what you seem to be doing.

Comment: I edited your answer- hopefully you agree with it! Interesting solution. It would be nice to see exactly how the circles are determined though, since right now it just appears "by construction". Let $c_{ij}$ and $r_{ij}$ be the center and radius of circle ${ij}$. What is the function $\{c_{ij}, r_{ij}\} = f(P_i, P_j, \beta_{ij})$ that exists "by the inscribed angle theorem"? Once this $f$ can be written, your solution can be coded up. You provided this function for the special case of $\beta_{ij} = \pi/2$ already.

Comment: @jnez71 I added a geometric construction of the center!

Comment: I see, thanks! One of the main benefits of the estimation-theory-based approach of my answer was that we also get an uncertainty estimate (the confidence ellipse in my animations). In the second demo with extreme noise, we see that the ellipse still tells us the spatial direction along which we are least certain. (And once converged, the 95% ellipse is reasonably tight and captures the truth)!

Comment: There might be a way to combine our techniques... first by pushing the noise distribution through the transformation that converts bearings into circles, and then using an EKF (recursive *probabilistically weighted* least-squares) to solve the multi-circle intersection problem. It might work better because the circle intersection problem is more linear than the direct model I used. On the other hand it might be no more accurate because the transformation from bearing measurements to circles involves the same $\tan$ that made my model nonlinear. Probably the latter, but that's just my hunch.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the $\ i=1,2,...,n\ $ bearing measurements can be expressed as,
$$
\alpha_i = \angle\delta_i - \alpha_0
$$
where $\alpha_0$ is the unknown angle from $x_1$ to $\hat{x}_1$ and
$$
\delta_i := P_i-P_0\\
\angle\delta_i = \tan^{-1}({\delta_i}_2\ /\ {\delta_i}_1)
$$

If we define,
$$
q := \begin{bmatrix} P_0 \\ \alpha_0 \end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \ \ z := \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n \end{bmatrix}
$$
and assume our bearing sensor is subject to additive noise then we can write,
$$
z = h(q) + \epsilon
$$
as our complete measurement model, where $\epsilon$ is a random variable with some known characteristics, like perhaps zero mean and covariance $R$.

It would also be nice / common to have some "prior" probabilistic information about our state $q$. That is, even if we don't know it exactly, we do have a hunch about what it could be, described by a probability distribution $q \sim \rho(q)$.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to reformulate $h(q)$ to be linear in $q$, so I can't just provide you with the closed-form optimal solution: i.e. the $q$ that maximizes the conditional probability distribution $\rho(q|z)$. As far as I can tell, we can only approximate this solution using the general approaches of nonlinear estimation theory.

I implemented an [extended Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter) as a first attempt. This involves a linearization of $h(q)$, so I computed its Jacobian by hand,
$$
\frac{dh_i}{dq} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{{\delta_i}_2}{||\delta_i||^2_2} & \frac{{-\delta_i}_1}{||\delta_i||^2_2} & -1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Another thing to note is that since we are dealing with angles, our measurements (and part of the state) are really members of $\mathbb{SO}2$ not $\mathbb{R}$. Thus we must be careful to work in the Lie algebra, which for this simply means "unwrapping" any angle differences onto $[-\pi, \pi]$.

To fully realize your problem, I have assumed that the additive bearing sensor noise is Gaussian with zero mean and a standard deviation of $5$ degrees. I arbitrarily placed $7$ landmarks. The animation below shows the EKF converging. I start with an incorrect state guess and a large covariance to reflect my prior uncertainty. You can also see that the bearing measurements (yellow rays) don't quite hit their respective landmarks (green dots).
[image: EKF Converging - 5deg sensor noise]
Obviously the "process model" in this case is stationary (the true state isn't moving). I linearize about the first guess, compute the best linear estimator (i.e. EKF corrector step), then relinearize about the updated mean and "reset" my covariance back to the prior before attempting another linearization & update. *To be clear, only $7$ measurements total were taken (one for each landmark), and all $7$ are incorporated at the same time - the "iterations" are just relinearizations.* The [code is here](https://github.com/jnez71/misc/blob/master/estimation/resection_ekf.py). If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Here is one more visualization this time giving the bearing sensor rediculous noise - a standard deviation of $30$ degrees (you can see how way-off the yellow rays are). The filter still does a good job, with its posterior covariance reasonably reflecting the direction along which we still have uncertainty. Note that heading always converges well because the sensor model is actually linear in that state.
[image: EKF Converging - 30deg sensor noise]

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the effort you put into this so very well written post. I did not know about the extended KF, and it was very interesting to learn about it in this context. I do have a few questiosn: (a) Is it correct that this is an approach you came up with (and that is not necessarily known otherwise)?  (b) We need an initial guess - is it correct that we could theoretically use any point? (Obviously e.g. a centroid of the points $P_i$ would make sense in a lot of applications.)

Comment: (c) Is it guaranteed to converge (for $\epsilon \to 0$, and up to the degenerate cases - for instance when all points including the unknown position are close to being on one circle)? (d)  Can we say anything about the "convergence rate"? (that is how quickly the estimates converge (not necesarily the exact solution)).

Comment: @flawr Well thank you for the interesting problem! (a) The Kalman filter and its variants typically come to mind for problems like these, as it is a cornerstone of [sensor fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion). (b) In Bayesian approaches like the Kalman filter, the "initial guess" is really a prior probability distribution for the thing we're estimating. Theoretically we can place the mean (or mode) anywhere as long as the spread is large enough to capture the truth within a couple standard deviations.

Comment: For example, even if I guess a mean near the truth, if I make the initial covariance really tiny, the filter will be "too confident" in the prior and barely move even after incorporating all the measurements. (c) In a degenerate scenario we would say that the state is unobservable from the measurement model. Ideally we'd be left with a posterior probability distribution that shows us the subspace along which we can't determine the state.

Comment: (d) Kalman filters are very similar to [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization), so convergence should be [quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton's_iterative_method).

Comment: Thanks for answering my follow up questions!

Comment: @flawr Out of curiosity, how else could I help make this an acceptable answer?

Comment: It is a lot more than acceptable, I just didn't accept it yet because I hoped someone could provide an algorithm that is used in practice. But it doesn't seem that anyone else is going to answer now, but I'm gonna wait a little more. I do highly appreciate your answer, and it is not the case that something is wrong with it, I just didn't accept yet, as this usually marks a question as "completely answered/solved".

Comment: @flawr I see, no worries! But so you know, the EKF is used extensively in practice (it is notoriously ubiquitous) for any kind of "noisy measurement" geometry problem. For example, the GPS problem is very similar to this, but you have noisy ranges rather than bearings, and the EKF is a very common solution. In robotics, scanning sensors like LIDARs are used which provide noisy range and bearing measurements, and some of the first common solutions for LIDAR navigation were EKF-based, like [EKF-SLAM](https://goo.gl/bpzxaT) (Figure 1 should look familiar).

Comment: @flawr I was looking at some of my old answers and came across this - time to accept yet? lol
(But really, the EKF is a cornerstone of any problem asking to "estimate [thing] from noisy [stuff] measurements", especially those with highly geometrical models. Any delve into applied estimation theory reveals this. Even one of the commenters mentioned the KF.)