# Get position and heading from noisy azimuth/distance measurements

Tags: trigonometry

I've been struggling with the following navigation problem. I have a set of known points in a plane, a set of *noisy* distance and azimuth measurements associated with these points and I want to compute the position and heading of the vehicle. As I used to work in the GNSS industry, I can easily determine the position based on distances only, but that is not enough - I don't use all the information I have ([One situation that is extremely inaccurate to be solved by distances only, but with azimuths it should be much closer to the truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7zfY.png)).

I've been looking far and wide, but unfortunately, haven't found any set of equations describing this scenario. I have found [position estimation from angles only](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797879/how-to-estimate-position-from-noisy-angles), but these don't have the distance measurements :-) And I cannot come up with anything useful on my piece of paper...

Thanks in advance for any nudge.

---

**EDIT**: clarification on measurements noise.

In GNSS, the navigation problem is solved by having an estimated position, linearizing the equations around it and constructing a geometry matrix $G$, weighting matrix $W$ and using WLS: $e=\left(G^TWG\right)^{-1}G^TW\cdot\Delta\rho$, where $\Delta\rho$ is the vector of measurement residuals (expected minus measured pseudorange) and $e$ the error vector - the vector that points to the new position estimate. You iterate until $||e||$ gets small enough.

The thing is that $G$'s columns are $x$, $y$, $z$ (and some time vars), as are the elements of $e$. Now that I have also azimuth measurements, I cannot come up with something sane, how to use it - I know it somehow "limits" the relationship of respective $x$'s and $y$'s, but how to fuse them and compute the error vector $e$, that's the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you know azimuth and distance you know the position, in polar coordinates.
If you convert a pair of polar coordinates to XY you can write an equation for the line connecting them by the 2 point method. Once you have that put the equation into the point-slope form. The slope is the tangent of the heading.

Comment: BTW, you can't determine position from either range alone or azimuth alone. With a series of ranges the only useful result  is CPA - closest point of approach to the observer. With azimuths alone the only useful result is heading. Both calculations require that the vehicle stay on a course at constant speed.

Comment: Thanks! However, the measurements I have are _noisy_, which I should have emphasized in my question (and will edit it accordingly). Your suggestion only works if there is zero error in the measurements, or if I only have one measurement.
Regarding your comment: don't understand it, since GNSS is based on determining position from ranges alone; and the linked position estimation from azimuths alone also solves the position...